# The generated AMD file is not including required files inside anonymous function and pollute the global namespace

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gulp, amd

The generated AMD file is not including required files inside anonymous function and pollute the global namespace

I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined`

The generated js file `https://dadasay.com/plugin/v1/js/dadasay.min.js` is not including required files `require.js`

The js file generated by running`gulp minify_plugin_js`

However, the expected export js file should be like this `https://gist.github.com/anonymous/32894a4065ce338fb0416f4eb2b884dd`

How could I do that in Gulp js and require.js

## require.js config

```
    'use strict';

    var vendor_paths = {
        require: './vendor/require',
        jquery: './vendor/js/jquery-2.1.1.min',
        ...
    }

    require.config({
        paths: vendor_paths,
        hbs: { // optional
            helpers: true,            // default: true
            templateExtension: 'hbs', // default: 'hbs'
            partialsUrl: ''           // default: ''
        },

        shim: {
            handlebars: {
                exports: 'Handlebars'
            },
            backbone: {
                deps: [
                    'jquery',
                    'underscore'
                ],
                exports: 'Backbone'
            },
            underscore: {
                exports: '_'
            }
        },

    });

    require(["app"],function(App){

        define(["app"], function (App) {
            $("#dadasay_comments_plugin").hide();
            $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href='+cfg.css_style_link+' type="text/css" />');
            return App.initialize();
        });

    });
```

## Gulp config

```
    var v1_assets = {
      css: ['public/plugin/v1/css/*.css'],
      js: ['public/plugin/v1/src/**/*.js'],
      require_manifest_file: "public/plugin/v1/src/main.js"

    }
    gulp.task('minify_plugin_js',function(){
        gulp.src(v1_assets.js)
            .pipe(amdOptimize("main",{
                configFile: v1_assets.require_manifest_file,
                findNestedDependencies: true,
                include: true
            }))
            .pipe(concatFile('dadasay.min.js'))
    })
```

## Exported js min file

```
https://dadasay.com/plugin/v1/js/dadasay.min.js

define('app_config', [], function () {

    return {
        server_host: SERVER_HOST,
        hideCommentsThreshouldNumber: 3,
        comments_req_prefix: SERVER_HOST + '/api/v1/comments/load?og_url=',
        css_style_link: [
            SERVER_HOST,
            PLUGIN_LOCATION,
            'style.min.css'
        ].join('/')
    };
});
....
```

Comment: What is `amdOptimize`? Some plugin for gulp?

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
define(["app"], function (App) {
```

is unnecessary. You required your application asynchronously already.

I believe that you could try to use the requirejs optimizer directly within gulp instead, here's how my build task looks like:

```
"use strict";

const requirejs = require("requirejs");
const path = require("path");
const _ = require("underscore");

module.exports = function (options, callback) {

    // RequireJS Optimizer Build Configuration
    // See this: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js
    // as an example file that details all of the allowed optimizer configuration options.
    var buildConfig = {
        appDir: options.dest,
        baseUrl: "./",
        optimize: "uglify2",
        optimizeCss: "standard",
        findNestedDependencies: true,
        dir: options.build,
        removeCombined: true,
        fileExclusionRegExp: options.exclude || /test/,
        modules: options.modules || [{
            name: "runner"
        }],
        allowSourceOverwrites: true
    };
    var config = path.join(__dirname + "/../../", options.config);
    var requireConfig = require(config);
    _.extend(buildConfig, requireConfig);
    requirejs.optimize(buildConfig, function (text) {
        callback(null, text);
    }, callback);

};
```

And then later in gulp:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const build = require("../task/build.task");

gulp.task("build", function (callback) {
    build({ some: "options" }, callback);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried gulp? I'd rather using gulp to build it

Comment: @newBike you can use other modules with gulp easily too, I've updated the answer

Comment: still not understand how to pass the config~~ what's the standard you are using?

Comment: I keep the config as json for simplicity (I reuse it for karma etc.), you can adjust the code and require it in any way you'd like to